# Excel File called with wrong file type

Tags: javascript, excel

so I made a JavaScript-Code that accesses a Excel (xlsx) file to retrieve values in cells, to calculate new ones and write them back into the same one. I was working with another Excel file with macros (xlsm) and wanted to use the same code for this file instead of the other one to write the data back. The problem now is that I used  workbook3.XLSX.readFile(excelFilePath2) for the Excel file with macros. Now the file seems corrupted, I can open it, but it does not show any data, almost all Excel-functions besides macros are greyed out, I cannot use AddIns either. Since I stupidly did not make a copy of the file before testing it I would like to retrieve the data. Luckily I saved the macros in editor files beforehand, but I would like to get the raw data and the diagramms to create a new Excel file. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Asking how to retrieve data from a corrupt file is not really in-scope for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Where else would I ask that?

Comment: Have you looked at all the [available tutorial and help articles](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?q=retrieve+data+from+corrupt+excel+file&cat=web&language=english)?

Comment: Yes I looked through dozens sides. I got a basic solution now where I simply use a new file where I say a field has a specific value from the corrupted workbook to get the raw data. But I still have no way to get the diagrams out of it.

Comment: Maybe try looking in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles
for the original - wonder if it may still be there

Comment: Was empty. But I got all the work redone, luckily I saved the programming codes in Microsoft Visual Basic beforehand. Now I am just saving every file twice in case I corrupt one